# Otimização de query SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, desempenho

Estou com um problema de desempenho na query abaixo. Tenho um banco de dados razoavelmente grande e com isso a execução do comando demora um bom tempo para ser executado.
O comando basicamente mostra algumas informações sobre produtos, taxas e a quantidade sugerida de produtos que o cliente deve comprar em produtos seguindo valores de quantidade por deposito data, quantidade vendida e etc(esta coluna é o problema). Preciso de dicas e sugestoes para melhoria de desempenho

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id                                                     AS
                'Cód. Produto',
                p.nome                                                   AS
                'Produto',
                (SELECT TOP 1 codigo_barras
                 FROM   produto_cod_barra
                 WHERE  id_produto = p.id)                               AS
                'Cód. Barras',
                (SELECT Sum(a.quantidade)
                 FROM   estoque a
                 WHERE  a.id_produto = p.id
                        AND a.id_deposito IN( 1 )
                        AND a.id_deposito IN (SELECT b.id
                                              FROM   deposito b
                                              WHERE  b.id_empresa = 1))  AS
                'ATALIBA - Estoque',
                CONVERT(INT, Isnull((SELECT Sum(a.quantidade)
                                     FROM   venda_item_produto a
                                            INNER JOIN venda aa
                                                    ON aa.id = a.id_venda
                                     WHERE  aa.id_empresa = 1
                                            AND p.id = a.id_produto
                                            AND aa.data BETWEEN
                                                '2022-09-01 00:00:00' AND
                                                '2022-11-30 23:59:00'
                                            AND aa.cancelada = 'N'), 0)) AS
                'ATALIBA - Qtde. Vendida',
                Isnull((SELECT Sum(pit.quantidade)
                        FROM   pedido_item pit
                               INNER JOIN pedido ped WITH (nolock)
                                       ON ped.id = pit.id_pedido
                        WHERE  ped.realizou_entrada = 0
                               AND ped.cancelado = 0
                               AND ped.id_empresa = 1
                               AND pit.id_produto = p.id), 0)            AS
                'ATALIBA - Qtde. Pedida',
                Isnull(Cast((SELECT Sum(a.valor_custo)
                             FROM   produto_empresa a
                             WHERE  a.id_produto = p.id
                                    AND a.id_empresa = 1) /
                            (SELECT Count(a.valor_custo)
                             FROM   produto_empresa a
                             WHERE  a.id_produto = p.id
                                    AND a.id_empresa = 1) AS
                                   DECIMAL(10, 2)), 0)                   AS
                'ATALIBA - Custo Un',
                Cast(p.valor_negociacao AS DECIMAL(18, 2))               AS
                'Valor Negociação',
                depa.departamento                                        AS
                'Departamento',
                cate.categoria                                           AS
                'Categoria',
                subc.subcategoria                                        AS
                'Sub-Categoria',
                marca.marca                                              AS
                'Marca',
                Cast(CASE
                       WHEN RIGHT(CASE
                                    WHEN Isnull((
                                    ( (SELECT Sum(a.quantidade)
                                       FROM   venda_item_produto a
                                              INNER JOIN venda aa
                                                      ON
                                              aa.id = a.id_venda
                                       WHERE  Cast(aa.data AS DATE
                                              ) BETWEEN
                                              '2022-09-01 00:00:00' AND
                                              '2022-11-30 23:59:00'
                                              AND aa.id_empresa = 1
                                              AND p.id = a.id_produto
                                              AND aa.cancelada = 'N') / ((
                                             Cast(( CASE
                                                      WHEN Datediff(day,
                                                           '2022-09-01 00:00:00'
                                                           ,
                                                           '2022-11-30 23:59:00'
                                                           )
                                                           + 1 = 0 THEN 1
                                                      ELSE Datediff(day,
                                                           '2022-09-01 00:00:00'
                                                           ,
                                                           '2022-11-30 23:59:00'
                                                           )
                                                           + 1
                                                    END ) AS INT) )) * 91 ) -
                                                    (SELECT
                                    Sum(CASE
                                          WHEN a.quantidade < 0
                                        THEN 0
                                          WHEN a.quantidade >=
                                               0 THEN
                                          a.quantidade
                                          ELSE 0
                                        END)
                                                     FROM   estoque a
                                                     WHERE  a.id_produto = p.id
                                                            AND a.id_deposito IN
                                                    (SELECT b.id
                                                     FROM   deposito b
                                                     WHERE  b.id_empresa =
                                                            1))
                                         ), 0) < 0 THEN 0
                                    ELSE Isnull((
                                  ( (SELECT Sum(a.quantidade)
                                     FROM   venda_item_produto a
                                            INNER JOIN venda aa
                                                    ON
                                            aa.id = a.id_venda
                                     WHERE  Cast(aa.data AS DATE
                                            ) BETWEEN
                                            '2022-09-01 00:00:00' AND
                                            '2022-11-30 23:59:00'
                                            AND aa.id_empresa = 1
                                            AND p.id = a.id_produto
                                            AND aa.cancelada = 'N') / ((
                                           Cast(( CASE
                                                    WHEN Datediff(day,
                                                         '2022-09-01 00:00:00',
                                                         '2022-11-30 23:59:00')
                                                         + 1 = 0 THEN 1
                                                    ELSE Datediff(day,
                                                         '2022-09-01 00:00:00',
                                                         '2022-11-30 23:59:00')
                                                         + 1
                                                  END ) AS INT) )) * 91 ) -
                                                  (SELECT
                                  Sum(CASE
                                        WHEN a.quantidade < 0
                                      THEN 0
                                        WHEN a.quantidade >=
                                             0 THEN
                                        a.quantidade
                                        ELSE 0
                                      END)
                                                   FROM   estoque a
                                                   WHERE  a.id_produto = p.id
                                                          AND a.id_deposito IN
                                                  (SELECT b.id
                                                   FROM   deposito b
                                                   WHERE  b.id_empresa =
                                                          1))
                                       ), 0)
                                  END, 5) > 0 THEN
                       Cast(CASE WHEN Isnull((((SELECT
                       Sum(a.quantidade)
                       FROM venda_item_produto a
                       INNER JOIN venda aa ON aa.id = a.id_venda
                       WHERE
                       Cast(aa.data AS DATE) BETWEEN
                       '2022-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-11-30 23:59:00'
                       AND aa.id_empresa = 1 AND p.id = a.id_produto AND
                       aa.cancelada = 'N') / ((Cast((CASE WHEN Datediff(
                       day, '2022-09-01 00:00:00', '2022-11-30 23:59:00')
                       + 1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE Datediff(day,
                       '2022-09-01 00:00:00', '2022-11-30 23:59:00') + 1
                       END) AS INT))) *91) - (SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN
                       a.quantidade < 0 THEN 0 WHEN a.quantidade >= 0
                       THEN
                       a.quantidade ELSE 0 END) FROM estoque a WHERE
                       a.id_produto =
                       p.id AND a.id_deposito IN (SELECT b.id FROM
                       deposito b
                       WHERE b.id_empresa = 1 ))), 0) < 0 THEN 0 ELSE
                       Isnull((((SELECT Sum(a.quantidade) FROM
                       venda_item_produto a INNER JOIN venda aa ON aa.id
                       = a.id_venda WHERE Cast(aa.data AS DATE) BETWEEN
                       '2022-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-11-30 23:59:00'
                       AND aa.id_empresa = 1 AND p.id = a.id_produto AND
                       aa.cancelada = 'N' ) / ((Cast((CASE WHEN Datediff(
                       day, '2022-09-01 00:00:00', '2022-11-30 23:59:00')
                       + 1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE Datediff(day,
                       '2022-09-01 00:00:00', '2022-11-30 23:59:00') + 1
                       END) AS INT))) *91) - (SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN
                       a.quantidade < 0 THEN 0 WHEN a.quantidade >= 0
                       THEN
                       a.quantidade ELSE 0 END) FROM estoque a WHERE
                       a.id_produto =
                       p.id AND a.id_deposito IN (SELECT b.id FROM
                       deposito b
                       WHERE b.id_empresa = 1 ))), 0) END AS INT) + 1
                       ELSE
                         CASE
                           WHEN Isnull(( ( (SELECT Sum(a.quantidade)
                                            FROM   venda_item_produto a
                                                   INNER JOIN venda aa
                                                           ON aa.id = a.id_venda
                                            WHERE  Cast(aa.data AS DATE) BETWEEN
                                                   '2022-09-01 00:00:00' AND
                                                   '2022-11-30 23:59:00'
                                                   AND aa.id_empresa = 1
                                                   AND p.id = a.id_produto
                                                   AND aa.cancelada = 'N') / ((
                                                  Cast(( CASE
                                                           WHEN Datediff(day,
                                                  '2022-09-01 00:00:00',
                                                  '2022-11-30 23:59:00')
                                                  + 1 = 0 THEN 1
                                                           ELSE Datediff(day,
                                                  '2022-09-01 00:00:00',
                                                  '2022-11-30 23:59:00')
                                                  + 1
                                                         END ) AS INT) )) * 91 )
                                         -
                                                         (SELECT
                                         Sum(CASE
                                               WHEN a.quantidade < 0
                                             THEN 0
                                               WHEN a.quantidade >= 0
                                             THEN
                                               a.quantidade
                                               ELSE 0
                                             END)
                                                          FROM   estoque a
                                                          WHERE
                                         a.id_produto = p.id
                                         AND a.id_deposito IN
                                             (SELECT b.id
                                              FROM   deposito b
                                              WHERE  b.id_empresa = 1))
                                              ), 0) < 0 THEN 0
                           ELSE Isnull(( ( (SELECT Sum(a.quantidade)
                                            FROM   venda_item_produto a
                                                   INNER JOIN venda aa
                                                           ON aa.id = a.id_venda
                                            WHERE  Cast(aa.data AS DATE) BETWEEN
                                                   '2022-09-01 00:00:00' AND
                                                   '2022-11-30 23:59:00'
                                                   AND aa.id_empresa = 1
                                                   AND p.id = a.id_produto
                                                   AND aa.cancelada = 'N') / ((
                                                  Cast(( CASE
                                                           WHEN Datediff(day,
                                                  '2022-09-01 00:00:00',
                                                  '2022-11-30 23:59:00')
                                                  + 1 = 0 THEN 1
                                                           ELSE Datediff(day,
                                                  '2022-09-01 00:00:00',
                                                  '2022-11-30 23:59:00')
                                                  + 1
                                                         END ) AS INT) )) * 91 )
                                         -
                                                         (SELECT
                                         Sum(CASE
                                               WHEN a.quantidade < 0
                                             THEN 0
                                               WHEN a.quantidade >= 0
                                             THEN
                                               a.quantidade
                                               ELSE 0
                                             END)
                                                          FROM   estoque a
                                                          WHERE
                                         a.id_produto = p.id
                                         AND a.id_deposito IN
                                             (SELECT b.id
                                              FROM   deposito b
                                              WHERE  b.id_empresa = 1))
                                              ), 0)
                         END
                     END AS INT)                                         AS
                'ATALIBA - Sugestão'
FROM   produto p WITH (nolock)
       LEFT JOIN produto_empresa pe
              ON pe.id_produto = p.id
       LEFT JOIN produto_departamento depa
              ON depa.id = p.id_departamento
       LEFT JOIN produto_categoria cate
              ON cate.id = p.id_categoria
       LEFT JOIN produto_subcategoria subc
              ON subc.id = p.id_subcategoria
       LEFT JOIN produto_marca marca
              ON marca.id = p.id_marca
       LEFT JOIN produto_fornecedor pf
              ON pf.id_produto = p.id
WHERE  pe.ativo = 1
-- AND pf.ID_Fornecedor = 130720
ORDER  BY p.id
```

Comment: *" demora um bom tempo para ser executado"*... *"Preciso de dicas e sugestoes para melhoria de desempenho"* o que quer dizer "um bom tempo2? não tem como ajudar muito só vendo a query, você precisa executar um exec plan, analisar a query, os problemas e onde pode melhorar, falta detalhes, adicione o exec plan da query na pergunta para poder perceber melhor o problema

Comment: questao de tempo me refiro a cerca de 4 a 5 minutos de execução

Comment: Subselects como coluna sãp em geral lentos , algumas destas tabelas sãp chamadas mais de uma vez . Não poderiam estar no "join" ? Tem horasem que se fazer algo do zero é melhor que remendar algo que está ruim.

Comment: Outra coisa é indentar , fica melhor de entender.